# How to pass argument to constructor for middleware?

Tags: node.js, express

Suppose I want to do this:

```
app.use('/user/login', require('./routes/user.route.js')(variable));
```

I can't because I will get:

> TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a undefined

How can I pass `variable` to `user.route` constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `user.route.js`, you need to export something like this :

```
module.exports = function (variable) {
    return (req, res, next) => {
        // your middleware
        next()
    }
}
```

Or with currying (https://wsvincent.com/javascript-currying/):

```
module.exports = variable => (req, res, next) => {
   const myUsedVariable = variable + 1
   res.send(myUsedVariable)
}
```

And if you're using express.Router:

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Birds home page')
})

module.exports = variable => {
   // do something with your variable
   router.use(function displayVariable(req, res, next) {
      console.log(variable)
      next()
   })

   return router
}
```

Comment: it's a good way to define `var express = require('express')` in each router?

Comment: In a performance way ? The require mechanism handle this fine  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8887318/understanding-node-js-modules-multiple-requires-return-the-same-object